# AABB implementation

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, physics

I have seen in some texts and tutorials on the web where an AABB is implemented as a position vector and then half-width and half-height vectors.  What is the advantage in using the half-width and half-height vectors?  Why not use the full width and height vectors?

Comment: More info in related question [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57515/why-would-you-use-a-negative-value-for-bounding-box)

Answer (score 2):

You then have the centers of the BB without having to know the size of it, if your game needs to know the centers more often than the top left then that is preferable.

Storing the half vectors is to simplify retrieving the left/right and bottom/top vectors center-halfHeight provides the bottom and center+halfHeight provides the top. Granted all it does is avoid dividing by 2 but when it's done often enough the difference can be felt.